# Expected value random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I have to calculate $ EY $

X ~ $ exp(1/100) $
$$
Y = \left\{ \begin{array}{11}
0 & \textrm{for $X<20$ }\\
X-20 & \textrm{for 20 $\leq$ X <280}\\
280 & \textrm{for $ 280 < X $}
\end{array} \right.
$$

$ EY=0 \cdot \int_{0}^{20}x \frac{1}{100} \exp(\frac{-1}{100}x)dx + \int_{0}^{280}x \frac{1}{100} \exp(\frac{-1}{100}(x+20))dx + 280 (1-\int_{0}^{20}x \frac{1}{100} \exp(\frac{-x}{100})dx - \int_{0}^{280}x \frac{1}{100} \exp(\frac{-1}{100}(x+20))dx) $

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is I think you're overcomplicating it, and as a result I think your result has numerical errors. To find $E[Y]$, you need to integrate $Y(X)P(X)dX$ over all $X$, which in this case is $X \in [0,\infty)$. $Y(X)$ is as you've defined above, and $P(X) = \frac{1}{100}\exp{\left(-\frac{1}{100}X\right)}$. So you need to sum three integrals, corresponding to the three regimes of $Y$'s behaviour:

$$I_{1} = \int_{0}^{20} 0 \cdot \frac{1}{100}\exp{\left(-\frac{1}{100}X\right)}dX$$
$$I_{2} = \int_{20}^{280} (X-20) \cdot \frac{1}{100}\exp{\left(-\frac{1}{100}X\right)}dX$$
$$I_{3} = \int_{280}^{\infty} 280 \cdot \frac{1}{100}\exp{\left(-\frac{1}{100}X\right)}dX$$

The first is clearly zero, and you should be able to evaluate the other two.

Comment: I  don't think this question makes sense, this question really messed up the convention on random variate and domain.  That is my feel.  Your answer is to an ill-defined question.  I hope people agree.

Comment: I agree it's not totally transparent, but to me it seems like the interpretation is that $X$ is exponentially distributed, and $Y$ is in turn dependent on $X$ as described. Posed that way, the problem is fully tractable. I can't see any other way of interpreting it.

Comment: I got this exercise in this form.
Thank you for solving